# Touchpad Issues?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I am kind of new to Ubuntu, and I love using it, but I hate the touchpad sensitivity in it. My touchpad works fine on Windwos, but in Ubuntu its very hard to work with.

It closes tabs without tapping and paste text while I am scrolling a text file, its just crazy and driving me crazy.

I have tried to install `GPointing Device Settings` to control the sensitivity and the tapping, but it didn't make any difference. I ended up disabling the tapping, but I can not get used to this.

I also tried to control it through changing the values by xinput --set-prop, but it disabled my touchpad.

There must be another solution for this !

How to solve this ?

Comment: do you happen to be using 3 fingers when this happens?

Comment: @virtualxtc no..not even 2 :)

Comment: I feel your pain, I hate touchpads; I'd much rather have a small trackball.  Perhaps playing around with daemon or xinput will help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: @virtualxtc Thanks...I have tried this before, and I ended up with a disabled touchpad, but thanks though :)

Comment: really? you should be able to gradually ramp down sensitivity via xinput (I only used syndaemon I was using arch linux when I was fixing my sensitivity problems and xinput wasn't installed)

Comment: @virtualxtc Yes I have tried using xinput with the same values as mentioned, but it disabled my touchpad.

Comment: You should revise your question to reflect the work you've already done and it likely will get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but I now remember when I last experienced exactly this issue.  There is a known bug with many touch-pads and certain power supplies, especially on circuits where CFL lights are being used.

To test this, just unplug your power cord from your computer and try using the touch pad.

If things are now smooth, you have a power conditioning problem.  If you are unable to find an alternative "cleaner" AC circuit, then you'll need to add a power conditioner to the circuit you are trying to use; or get rid of all CFLs on that circuit.